# python and rolling a die a set 1000 times

Tags: python

The purpose of this homework problem is to simulate rolling a six-sided die multiple  times, and tabulating the results using a list. You will write a function simulates rolling a die 1000 times,  and returns a list of six values representing the number of times that each side of the die appears. Call  this function rollDie(). For example, rollDie() could return the list [100,200,300,200,100,100]. For this  problem, the number of times that the die is rolled will always be 1000. For this problem, use a for loop.
This is the question for my homework assignment yet I am extremely lost when it comes to python. this is what I have so far...

```
import random

def rollDie():
    myList= ['100','200','300','400','500','600']
    myList= random.shuffle ['0,5']

    number=input("How many times should the die be rolled: ")
    return myList
```

Comment: `help(random.shuffle)` + if still confused use google.

Comment: @nick: please try to implement the `for` loop. you have the number of times it should run. tip: `range`.

Comment: Did you mean **dice**?

Comment: no, its just one die with 6 sides. Not sure how to get it to roll 1000 times or how to shuffle numbers 1-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not right for us to write this whole code for you, but we can give you pointers. Open a new question if you get stuck (and try to be more specific in future! Broken code is better than missing code!).

- `rollDie` returns an array with the number of rolls for each of 1 to 6, so start by creating that array, called `rolls`. Before any die has been rolled what should the array be initialised to? Set it to that value.
- Now we need to simulate rolling a die 1000 times. So, write some code that will do the same thing 1000 times.
- The thing that must be done 1000 times is a simulated dice roll. This is like a random number from 1 to 6. Write code that does that, and stores the result in a variable called `roll`.
- Before we leave the looped code, we need to use `roll` to make some change to the value we're returning (`rolls`). What effect does each roll have on `rolls`? Write the code for that (and remember that Python arrays are indexed from 0).
- Now, we've simulated the dice rolls and gathered the results, we just have to return them to whoever called our function.