# I want to run a simple die program in python that rolls a six sided die 10 times but the program does not

Tags: python, random, dice

I wanted this dice program to simulate the roll of a six sided die everytime I roll the six sided die ten times using a forloop.

As I stated, I wrote a for loop and specified the number of times I wanted the six sided die to roll.

```
import random
class Die():

    def __init__(self):
        self.sides=6

    def roll_die(self):
        dice=random.randint(1,self.sides)
        for dice in range(11):
            print("Rolling "+str(dice))

dice_roll=Die()
print("=========================================================")
dice_roll.roll_die()
```

output:

```
=========================================================
Rolling 0
Rolling 1
Rolling 2
Rolling 3
Rolling 4
Rolling 5
Rolling 6
Rolling 7
Rolling 8
Rolling 9
Rolling 10
```

I expected the for loop in my simulation to print a bunch of random numbers that range from 1 to 6 ten times. Instead, it printed the numbers in order and did not only print numbers that ranged from 1 to 6.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079214/python-and-rolling-a-die-a-set-1000-times?rq=1

Comment: You used the name `dice` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Write you loop like this:

```
    for _ in range(10):
        dice=random.randint(1,self.sides)
        print("Rolling "+str(dice))
```

You don't need to have a variable in the for loop if you're only looking to loop a certain number of times without varying the process based on the iteration number.

In order to get a different dice value on each loop, you need to compute it inside the loop. You had it outside.  You were also overriding the random value you placed in the dice variable by using the same variable name in the for loop.

Comment: Could you please include in your answer why the change is necessary, so that the lesson is learned, in addition to the error being fixed?

Answer (score 1):

After the first time you assigned dice, `dice = random.randint(1, self.sides)` , you reassigned it in the next line. To fix this error, just change `for dice in range(11):` to something like `for i in range(11):`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are rolling the dice 11 times (0,1,2,...,10). If you want it just 10 times, your loop should be iterated using `range(10)`

Next, you used same variable dice for two things.

1. value of dice rolled
2. number of times the dice is rolled

You can either change to `dice_val = random.randint(1, self.sides)` and `print("Rolling "+str(dice_val))` or
change `for dice in range(11):` to something like `for roll_count in range(10):`